# Partition of natural number not equal to factorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

I wish to prove the following statement so I can use it as a lemma for a group theory result. To be honest I have not tried much yet, my intuition tells me this is going to be connected to the partition function or Euler's totient function, both of which are beyond my knowledge of number theory.

> Prove that the following cannot happen,
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} = d \text{ and } \text{LCM}(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{k}) = d!$$
>
> $k, a_{i}, d \in \mathbb{N}$. $1 \leq a_{i} \leq d$. $a_{i}$'s not
>   distinct. d > 2.

Any advice or comments greatly appreciated!

> update:

As mentioned in the comments, intent is to use this to show a symmetric group is not cyclic. Also, here is a possible re-structuring and an outline of my thoughts..

> It will suffice to show for $a_{i}, d \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $1 \leq
>  a_{i} \leq d$ and $2 < d$
>
> $$\text{If } \text{LCM}(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{k}) = d!, \text{ then }
>  \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} \neq d \text{ or } k > d$$

Idea: since $a_{i}'s < d$ except for when $a_{i} = d$ and $k = 1$, then it would imply that every number less than d was co prime which I can bring to a contradiction.

Comment: So you are trying to show that the symmetric group is not cyclic? First of all you need $d>2$. And second it seems easier to do this via the group, though probably one can make some estimates to show it.

Comment: > symbol was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft thats right. That is my goal. I would like to come at it this way since it was my own idea... and it seems like it shouldnt be too bad. My thought is that each $a_{i}$ must occur in the d! so for the products to be equal each $a_{i}$ must be coprime and the euler totient function probably says that cant happen?

Comment: Possibly. But it is practically trivial to show this using a bit of group theory instead. A cyclic group is abelian.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft What you are telling me is parallel to telling someone they shouldn't hike a mountain to see the view because they can find a picture on google images far easier. This is more about the process for me.

Comment: Hint for doing this directly: The LCM is a product of at most $d$ distinct numbers all at most $d$. This leaves only a specific case to rule out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $d\gt2$ and $\text{LCM}(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)=d!.$ We want to show that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k\gt d.$

Let $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ be the distinct prime divisors of $d!.$ From the fact that each $p_i$ divides some $a_j$ it easily follows that $a_1+\cdots+a_k\ge p_1+\cdots+p_n.$ So it will suffice to show that, for $d\gt2,$ the sum of the prime numbers $\le d$ is greater than $d.$ This can be proved by induction on $d,$ using [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), which says that for $m\gt1$ there is a prime between $m$ and $2m.$

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that
$\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} = d 
\text{ and } \text{LCM}(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{k}) = d!
$
can not happen.

For $k=1$,
$a_1 = d$
so this can and does happen
for $d \le 2$.
It does not happen for
$d \ge 3$.

For $k=2$,
you want
$lcm(a, d-a) = d!$
to not be.

The lcm is largest
when $a$ and $d-a$
are relatively prime,
so that
$lcm(a, d-a)
= a(d-a)
\le d^2/4
$.

Since
$d^2/4 < d!
\iff d/4 < (d-1)!
$
which is true for
$d \ge 1$,
your hope holds.

My next idea
would try a proof by induction
on $k$,
but it is late
and I am tired,
so I will leave it at this.